# Twilio voicemail when call is cut

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I have created a function for call forwarding on Twilio and if the call is not answered in 16 seconds, it will get redirected to voicemail. This function works fine but if the call is cut before 16 seconds, the local service provider's voice email audio is played up to 16 seconds and then the programmed voice mail audio.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can you share the code you are using? Which leg of the call is cut before the 16 seconds in the incorrect case? And what is result?